# Sub-Select com MAX / SUM / INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Preciso fazer um `SUM` dentro de um `MAX` para retornar o maior faturamento do produto dentro de uma sumarização.

Consegui fazendo isso:

```
SELECT MAX(Faturamento) MAX_Faturamento 
FROM (SELECT SUM(P.preco * I.qtde) Faturamento 
    FROM produto P 
    INNER JOIN itens I ON P.cod_prod = I.cod_prod 
    GROUP BY P.descricao) AS tabela_aux;
```

Porém também preciso trazer a descrição do produto, somente do produto que teve o maior faturamento. Tentei usando isso:

```
SELECT Descricao, MAX(Faturamento) MAX_Faturamento 
FROM (SELECT P.descricao, SUM(P.preco * I.qtde) Faturamento 
    FROM produto P INNER JOIN itens I ON P.cod_prod = I.cod_prod 
    GROUP BY P.descricao) AS tabela_aux 
GROUP BY Descricao;`
```

Porém ele me retorna todos os registros e eu preciso somente do que teve o maior faturamento.

Comment: MAX ORDER BY SUM DESC LIMIT , tente algo assim

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado, Motta! Consegui usando as ferramentas que você me proporcionou. Ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
'SELECT Descricao, MAX(Faturamento) Faturamento FROM (SELECT SUM(P.preco * I.qtde) Faturamento, P.descricao FROM produto P INNER JOIN itens I ON P.cod_prod = I.cod_prod GROUP BY P.descricao) AS tab_aux GROUP BY Descricao ORDER BY Faturamento DESC LIMIT 1;'
```

Comment: marque sua resposta como correta ;)